# xquery group by not elimilate duplicated items

Tags: xpath, xquery, xquery-3.0

I have an XML document,

```
<resultsets>
    <row>
        <first_name>Georgi</first_name>
        <last_name>Facello</last_name>
    </row>
    <row>
        <first_name>Bezalel</first_name>
        <last_name>Simmel</last_name>
    </row>
    <row>
        <first_name>Bezalel</first_name>
        <last_name>Hass</last_name>
    </row>
</resultsets>
```

I want to sort first names and remove duplicated first names to produce this:

```
<resultsets>
    <row>
        <first_name>Bezalel</first_name>
        <last_name>Simmel</last_name>
    </row>
    <row>
        <first_name>Georgi</first_name>
        <last_name>Facello</last_name>
    </row>
</resultsets>
```

Following are the code I wrote:

```
for $last_name at $count1 in doc("employees.xml")//last_name,
$first_name at $count2 in doc("employees.xml")//first_name
let $f := $first_name
where ( $count1=$count2 )
group by $f
order by $f
return 
<row> 
     {$f}
     {$last_name}
</row>
```

However, this code sort the XML document by first names, but failed to remove the duplicated first name ('Bezalel'), it returns:

```
   <resultsets>
        <row>
            <first_name>Bezalel</first_name>
            <last_name>Simmel</last_name>
        </row>
        <row>
            <first_name>Bezalel</first_name>
            <last_name>Hass</last_name>
        </row>
        <row>
            <first_name>Georgi</first_name>
            <last_name>Facello</last_name>
        </row>
    </resultsets>
```

I know how to solve this using two FLOWR statements. `group by` behavior is weird, could you please explain why it does not remove the duplicates? 
Is there any way we can solve this problem using **ONE** FLOWR loop and **ONLY** use `$first_name` and `$last_name` two variables? Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I would simply group the `row` elements by the `first_name` child and then output the first item in each group to ensure you don't get duplicates:

```
<resultssets>
{
    for $row in resultsets/row
    group by $fname := $row/first_name
    order by $fname
    return
        $row[1]    
}
</resultssets>
```

http://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyiVhf

As to how the `group by` clause works, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-group-by which says:

> The group by clause assigns each pre-grouping tuple to a group, and
>   generates one post-grouping tuple for each group. In the post-grouping
>   tuple for a group, each grouping key is represented by a variable that
>   was specified in a GroupingSpec, and every variable that appears in
>   the pre-grouping tuples that were assigned to that group is
>   represented by a variable of the same name, bound to a sequence of all
>   values bound to the variable in any of these pre-grouping tuples.